# Mxgraph How to add text element programmatically inside shape?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mxgraph

I want to add a text element inside any shape. I can add placeholder programmatically using the below code but could not able to move the text just able to change the style. I wanted to label should be moved at any position.

```
var applyBtn = mxUtils.button(mxResources.get('apply'), function()
    {
        try
        {
            ui.hideDialog.apply(ui, arguments);

            // Clones and updates the value
            value = value.cloneNode(true);
            var removeLabel = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
            {
                if (texts[i] == null)
                {
                    value.removeAttribute(names[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    value.setAttribute(names[i], texts[i].value);
                    //console.log(names[i]+"==="+texts[i].value);
                    removeLabel = removeLabel || (names[i] == 'placeholder' &&
                        value.getAttribute('placeholders') == '1');
                }
            }

            // Removes label if placeholder is assigned
            if (removeLabel)
            {
                value.removeAttribute('label');
            }
            // set booth id here
            value.setAttribute('label',value.getAttribute('booth_number'));
            graph.getModel().setValue(cell, value);
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            mxUtils.alert(e);
        }
    });
```

Output

[image]

Needed

[image: So I wanted to add text element so user can move position easily]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have checked https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/htmllabel.html , it gives me label at center position and couldn't allow me to change the position

Comment: You want to be able to change label position programatically or by dragging it in UI?

Comment: hi @Godric - I want to change label position by dragging the UI. The lable is append programetically but user allow to change position by dragging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like setting `graph.vertexLabelsMovable = true;` is what you are looking for.

Based on [this](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/labels.html) example (code [here](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/blob/master/javascript/examples/labels.html))